# Is it possible to make Drupal administrator more comfortable

Tags: theming

Is it possible to make Drupal administrator more comfortable? an GUI with icons instead of menu links?

Comment: You mean the admin-interface? There's a ton of good admin themes out there that make the surface a bit more manageable. Just google for "drupal admin themes" and you'll find more than enough, like this blog post: http://blogfreakz.com/cms/10-free-admin-theme-for-drupal/

Comment: Although it doesn't really change that fact that a lot of Drupal administration is horrible out-of-the-box for non-technical content administrators. Unfortunately the only ways to fix this is a) heavy context-specific customization b) praying in the name of Dries for real advances in Drupal 8.

Comment: Could be more specific as to what you think is comfortable? Like: custom navigation, aesthetics (admin theme), advanced content browsing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the [Root Candy](http://drupal.org/project/rootcandy/) theme which makes the admin interface look like this:

[image: root candy]

It also has a bunch of other features:

- Supports node/add /edit pages
- Re-colorable
- Icons
- Top navigation by role
- Simple dashboard
- 3 column fluid or fixed layouts
- Rootcandy dark sub-theme
- Icons in compact mode
- Sliding region

Comment: thank you, I installed it but don't see it like this picture. no icons for links inside the configuration section are shown.